# jsoup getting a particular value

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<div id="studentInfo">
<p id="studentdetails">
<span>Placeofbirth:</span>
   <span class="hidden" itemtype="http://xxxx.com" itemscope="">
    <a itemprop="url" href="xxx.xom">
    <span itemprop="title">Greg</span>
    </a>
    <span itemtype="http://xxxx1.com" itemscope="" itemprop="child">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/c/san-diego/indpak">
<span itemprop="title">Greg is one of the Best student</span>
</a>
</span>
</span>
<span id="cat_display">
<a href="xxx.com"> Greg can be promoted </a>
</span>
```

I did a

```
Element studentname = doc.select("div p ").first();
```

when I do :I am getting 
Greg Greg is one of the Best student  Greg can be promoted .

I want to print only:
Greg can be promoted

Looks when I do p, and try to print studentname.text()
it is printing all the text present, I was looking for one particular Text.

How can I acheieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Hope This is your Solution

```
Elements students = document.select("div p #cat_display");
System.out.println(students.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the better solution and quicker

```
String sText= document.select("span#cat_display").text();
System.out.println(sText);
```